# Where do I begin to solve this partial differential equation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Find all solutions $u(x,y)$ to the partial differential equation $$\frac{\partial^{2}{u}}{\partial{x^2}}+\frac{\partial^{2}{u}}{\partial{y^{2}}}= x^2+y^2$$ which only depends on $$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, \text{that is }u(x,y)=f(r).$$

My idea is to rewrite the problem with the following $$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}=\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{r}}\frac{\partial{r}}{\partial{x}}$$ And then the same with respect to y.

Comment: Convert the Laplacian into polar coordinates: $$\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\bigg(r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\bigg) + \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2}$$ and then use separation of variables.

Comment: I haven't worked with Laplace conversions yet...

Comment: By inspection, $\dfrac{x^4+y^4}{12}$ is a particular solution, and $u-\dfrac{x^4+y^4}{12}$ is an arbitrary harmonic function.

Comment: Hah clever @YvesDaoust . Love it.

Comment: @edwind , Cameron wasn't talking about Laplace transforms or anything. "The Laplacian" is the name for the quantity on the left side of your equation. And "convert" in this context just means "change variables"/"change to polar".

Comment: Oh I see, I managed to solve with another method though and I’m going to post my attempt but I’m slow with latex